# Bypassing Django's authentication and user model completely

Tags: python, django, django-users

So this is for a homework assignment where I have open choice to use any technology I want. Its a Databases course so the only requirement is that all my SQL should be raw and written by myself. I have been successful in doing that with everything, EXCEPT the user model.

What i'd like to achieve is basically use an existing database prepopulated with usernames and plain text passwords for authentication. Since this is homework, security is not a concern at all, the program will never go online.

I just want to use my existing database for authentication. My code is littered with LoginRequiredMixins etc so I need for my authentication to return a user object but bypass Django's user model fields and hashed passwords etc. I would also like to use my own field names for login etc. Instead of username and password, I'd like to have email and PIN.

I do not need any sign up pages or the ability for anyone to sign up, just what already exists in my table.

Any resources you could point me to or help on how one would achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you chose Django in that case? A stripped-down framework such as Flask would be more suitable if you don't want to use neither ORM nor the built-in authentication.

Comment: I realize now that I should have probably gone with flask but wanted to learn django so went with. Too late to change everything now.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely re-write Django's authentication system with your own. Here is a good example - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example.

You can create an app and declare your own user model. In the example, you can overwrite the user model with you're own fields:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

However, I would suggest using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), since it offers a lot more flexibility.

Hope this helps.